# Why does Update Manager give me a 404 error with these Google repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager, downloads

I have a red warning sign in my toolbar. When I click on it, it asks me to check for updates. When I check for updates, I get this:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/testing/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 74.125.227.46 80]    
W:Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/testing/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 74.125.227.46 80]
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This happened to me once before when 12.04 was still in beta, but I can't remember what I did. It was a *huge* mess!

**System:**
12.04 64-bit
Sony Vaio VGN-NW220F

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you (or a piece of Google software) added a Google repository that is no longer valid. This shouldn't prevent you from updating the rest of the system.

Comment: I added them a long time ago. They were working fine for Google Earth before.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever that Google repository was, it's gone now. If it was a PPA, you can try removing/unchecking it in Software Sources. If you added those lines manually to sources.list, remove and run sudo apt-get update.

Comment: I don't see those in Software Sources.

Comment: They aren't in sources.list either.

Comment: Please Pastebin the output of `ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1104122/

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: @Klikini: it does; `google.list` is probably what you want. To be sure, could you pastebin the output of `grep dl.google /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` ?

Comment: Here you go: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1106529/

Comment: I thought maybe Google went down, but no. It's been 2 weeks, and it would be back up by now. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Found a mirror of that site here: http://aptproxy.linuxdeepin.com/dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/testing/non-free/binary-i386/

Looks like it contained the apt repo for Picasa, which Google has officially discontinued for Linux.  Hence they pulled the plug on the repo itself.  Would have been nice if they simply left it up, but then again, this way you know it's gone and can move on (to the Windows Wine version).

Comment: I don't see the old one in the dialogue from the software centre or the sources.list file. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a perfect answer, but I reinstalled Ubuntu in a clean upgrade.