# Error message while trying to update/install a Google product

Tags: installation, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Update Manager give me a 404 error with these Google repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166186/why-does-update-manager-give-me-a-404-error-with-these-google-repositories)

```
W:Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)  
W:Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/testing/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 74.125.225.69 80]  
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The above is the error message I get when trying to use a google product. I tried changing server to main server but that didn't work. `apt-get update` gives same results.

Comment: It might help if we knew what google owned packages you're trying to use.

Comment: There are 2 ppa's with google in them. a stable and testing one. i guess its a kernel from google. idk why i have anything from google.